# Application bottlenecks testing software

Tags: profiling, performance-testing, benchmarking

For any generic software application, is there a method to identify bottlenecks in performance?  No source code available.  Consider off the shelf software.  Whether gaming, deep learning, CPU computing, encoding, etc.  Can you identify hardware that is limiting the application?  Maybe it is CPU, GPU, RAM speed, RAM memory limits causing swapping, hard disk read speed, network, etc.

Comment: Yes, profile it with HW performance counters, and kernel CPU and disk I/O utilization stats, to see which resource(s) it saturates.

Answer (score 0):

Use [perf](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html#StackTraces) utility on Linux. The link provide good examples to measure a host of performance related parameters of an application.